# What does [0], [1], ... in structure description means in X.509 RFC 5280?

Tags: ssl-certificate, x509certificate, x509, asn.1, der

I'm studying RFC 5280 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280) and have noticed strange marks ([0], [1], [2], [3]) in TBSCertificate structure definition

```
TBSCertificate  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
    version         [0]  EXPLICIT Version DEFAULT v1,
    serialNumber         CertificateSerialNumber,
    signature            AlgorithmIdentifier,
    issuer               Name,
    validity             Validity,
    subject              Name,
    subjectPublicKeyInfo SubjectPublicKeyInfo,
    issuerUniqueID  [1]  IMPLICIT UniqueIdentifier OPTIONAL,
                         -- If present, version MUST be v2 or v3
    subjectUniqueID [2]  IMPLICIT UniqueIdentifier OPTIONAL,
                         -- If present, version MUST be v2 or v3
    extensions      [3]  EXPLICIT Extensions OPTIONAL
                         -- If present, version MUST be v3
    }
```

In ASN.1 it codes using special bytes 0xA0, 0xA1, 0xA2, 0xA3. Can't find any explanation on these bytes encoding. Can someone explain me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a tagged type. See X.680 section 31.2. `[0]` means that the value is encoded with a context-specific class and number `0`. In DER (X.690 sections 8.1.2 and 8.14), a constructed context-specific class with number `0` is encoded as `0xA0`.

Comment: How do I know which type it going to represent under this context-specific conditions?

Comment: I don't understand your question in the comment above.  You might be misunderstanding what "context-specific" means.  There are four classes of tags in ASN.1: universal, application, context-specific, and private.  If the tag were written [APPLICATION 1] it would be an application tag.  As written, it is a context-specific tag.  Context-specific here does not mean there will be a different tag in different contexts.

This question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035349/how-does-0-and-3-work-in-asn1